# How to clean Movable Type cache in tag templates

Tags: movabletype

I have modified my MT templates and publish all my static files. However the tags templates are nor refreshed:

http://www.example.com/tags/tag-name/

It looks that they are cached inside the tagcache folder. How can I refresh them?

Thank you.

Comment: Show us the relevant parts of the code you've tried.

Comment: What version of Movable Type are you using (MT Advanced, MT Pro, MT Enterprise, MT Open Source) and which version number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MT does not produce such clean URLs for tags, it uses the internal search engine and URLs such as those: MT_HOME/mt-search.cgi?blog_id=1&tag=Tagname&limit=20

You need to tell us how http://www.example.com/tags/tag-name/ is really produced (either the MT template code or the web server rewrite rule that produce this clean URL scheme).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify more about your MT versions and how tags is implemented.

Usually, Tags are implemented using the internal search. this search have a life time that is 20 seconds by default. (see it you have SearchCacheTTL in your mt-config.cgi)

failing that, you can check the database and clear all the session raws that have kind="CS". (this is where the cache is. unless you are using memcache)

Good luck.